# Java compiler errors in DDE on new computer, works fine in old one

Tags: java, apache-poi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse, update-site

I have 2 computers running Domino Designer, On my new one I get java errors in a server based application and not on the old one.
I have installed the required package on both machines and I have the same compiler set in prefs.

The computer with errors is a new one running windows 10 and DDE 11.0.1 FP1 and the old one is running Windows 7 and DDE 11.0.1

there is probably some paths or something that I have forgotten to set but can't find it.

what can be the cause of these errors on my new machine?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are missing the `biz.webgate.dominoext.poi` OSGi bundle from the errors list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your target platform settings as blogged by Jesse Gallagher: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/058650E080E352178525832B00519D2C.