# Error XPages com.ibm.xsp.page.FacesPageException. com.ibm.xsp not found

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, hcl-notes

I am having the following error in the HCL Designer:

[image]

And this is the browser error when opening the nsf url:

> com.ibm.xsp.page.FacesPageException: Could not load page /Home.xsp because the corresponding class xsp.Home was not com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDispatcher.
> com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:77)
> com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:528)
> com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:596)
> com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:144)
> com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:254)
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:163)
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
> com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:600)
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1352)
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:877)
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:820)
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:589)
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1336)
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
> com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
> com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

I have included several Jars, but none seem to have all the necessary com.ibm.xsp packages.

[image]

Any solution?
I understand that it is a dependency problem.

Maybe I'm missing some undownloaded jar, but I don't know which one.

Comment: It's most likely due to a bug in Domino Designer. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63355117/785061 for details on how to fix it

Comment: Can you add a reproducer? A simple Page that exhibits the problem. Without sources it is anybody’s guess

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten, thank you very much.  I got it by modifying the Target Platform, and adding xercesimpl.jar for org.apache.xml errors.